# android - how to push notification (reminder) on a specific time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I checked almost all questions in stack overflow and also in google documentation and still couldn't understand what to use **exactly** for my cases.

What i want is, user will select reminder date in the app and in that time app will send a notification even **app is closed or phone restarted between remind set time and remind time.**

So what do i need to use? Which classes do i need? Broadcast Receiver, AlarmManager these two is enough or what? a sample of code 20-30 lines would be nice =)

Comment: So you are saying you didn't find and then saying are these two are enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need both a few things.

Setup:
You need to set your app to listen for the phone starting by registering for [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) intent in your manifest.

Basically you when your user selects the time, you will need to:

1. Save that time in a file/db/shared prefs.
2. Set the alarm manager to wake up your app at the right time
3. When the alarm manager sends
   you a broadcast, start a service to do the necessary work (broadcast
   receivers have to complete their work in a short amount of time, so
   it's better to start a service)
4. In your service, remove the time
   from your file/db/shared prefs

If your app ever gets the broadcast that the phone was rebooted, then all of your alarms are lost. You need to reset them using the times you saved in the file/db/shared prefs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I am using db for other purposes so i will store in db. But why not use broadcast receiver? I will wake the intent up and send notification that is it? It is not a long process so broadcast receiver is not enough?

Comment: It's the file/db access that in theory could take too long. If you're just sending a notification and accessing one file quickly it will probably be fine. I've seen very slow file access on lower end (and older) devices that could put you over that limit but you'll most likely be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check Android Developers website for calender intents so you can use them to determine the time etc.
On your broadcast receiver pass the details or timing to the broadcast receiver. Once you do that use the alarm manager etc to check if the time is perfect and simply send a push notification when the time is correct.

I say this assuming that you know already about the calendar, alarm manager, and broadcast receivers intents. If you don't I recommend googling the following with Android Developers appended to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use AlertManager.set to send notification on particular time.
2. For re-setting Alarm Notification, use

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".AfterBootReceiver" android:label="AfterBootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
   </intent-filter>
   ```

and

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){

    ...
    }
```

to reset AlarmManager.set after device re-booted.